# find a note by its color in Python music21

Tags: python, colors, music21

Using music21 in python, I need to select all the notes that are red so I can change them to black but I cannot seem to find a way to select notes by their color... Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Hi Klayrr, and welcome to SO! Could you also share what you have tried so far and/or specify the application?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The file I am working on is an MEI file originally but I converted it with music21 to use the functions on it.

Comment: The question seemed specific enough to me to be able to give an answer and a link to more information.

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct function to search for notes by color.  However, you could write a [Custom Filter](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_26_iterators.html#custom-filters) to do what you want:

```
from music21 import *

def redFilter(n: note.Note):
    if n.style.color == 'red':
        return True
    else:
        return False

# assuming sc is your score:

for n in sc[note.GeneralNote].addFilter(redFilter):
    n.style.color = 'black'
```

This uses music21 v7 syntax for calling `recurse().getElementsByClass(note.GeneralNote)` -- if you're not on v7.3 be sure to upgrade.  (if you're more advanced in Python, you could write the parameter to addFilter as a lambda function).